# Laravel 5.5: Get all registered routes in Service provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a new Service provider and need to get all the registered routes in it. But `Route::getRoutes()->getIterator()` is returning `null`.

This is my full code,

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class ApiVersionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function register()
    {
        if (Request::instance()->is('api/v*')) {
            $routes = [];
            foreach (Route::getRoutes()->getIterator() as $route) {
                if ((strpos($route->uri, 'api') !== FALSE) AND basename($route->uri) == basename(Request::instance()->path())) {
                    $routes[] = $route->uri;
                }
            }
            dd($routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an alternative way to attain routes here?

Comment: Can it be that you call this code before `RouteServiceProvider` is loaded?

Comment: In `app.php` its loaded after `RouteServiceProvider`

Comment: That is unfortunately not the same, as you can see int @matiit 's  answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers#the-boot-method

You should place your code inside of the `boot()` method.

> This method is called after all other service providers have been registered

Currently you are trying to use Route service before it is registered itself.

So it should look like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class ApiVersionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Using boot method to ensure it is executed when the Route service is ready to be used
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if (Request::instance()->is('api/v*')) {
            $routes = [];
            foreach (Route::getRoutes()->getIterator() as $route) {
                if ((strpos($route->uri, 'api') !== FALSE) AND basename($route->uri) == basename(Request::instance()->path())) {
                    $routes[] = $route->uri;
                }
            }

            // Do anything you need with $routes array.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it.
Thanks bro :)